# How can i make grid based level?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im learning unity and creating a level. This level is cube based. And my question is how can i build this level easy? I want to put these cubes into separeted places like in minecraft. I searched for tutorial but I found only how to do this in actual game, but I need it at projecting moment.

[image]

Edit:
I was looking tool like progrids, so it solved my problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a fixed level design, then you have multiple options like making data (probably JSON format) then read it at runtime, then create the cubes once you have data. You can create an editor to make the data creation easier.

```
for(int x = 0; x < grid_x; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < grid_y; y++)
    {
        //Instantiate cubes and set transform based on x, and y
    }
}
```

If you want a randomized level, then that's a different problem